# How can I relate two tables that are in different databases (SQL Server)?

Tags: sql-server, linqpad

I need to grab a value from a table in another database; if the tables were in the same database, it would be pretty easy, but since they are not, it complicates matters. I've tried this:

```
SELECT TOP 8 prosql05.sa.cpsdata.M.membername, 
             P.* 
FROM   prosql05.sa.bidata.priceexceptionhistorycsr P 
       JOIN prosql05.sa.cpsdata.members M 
         ON P.memberno = M.memberno 
WHERE  invoicedate BETWEEN '2016-09-04' AND '2016-09-10' 
ORDER  BY invoicedate
```

...but get the err msg (in LINQPad),

> Error 208: Invalid object name 'sa.BIData.PriceExceptionHistoryCSR'.

I'm pretty sure this is possible (since they are both on PROSQL05), but how?

The Connection selected in LINQPad is "*PROSQL05.sa.BIData*"

### UPDATE

I've changed my attempt to this:

```
select top 8 M.MemberName, P.* 
from PriceExceptionHistoryCSR P, PROSQL05.sa.CPSData M
where InvoiceDate between '2016-09-04' and '2016-09-10'
and M.MemberNo = P.MemberNo
order by invoicedate
```

...and now get, "*Error 208: Invalid object name 'PROSQL05.sa.CPSData'.*"

That makes more sense to me, but I still need to know how to make the table from the other database (Schema, IOW CPSData) accessible from the BIData schema/database.

### UPDATE 2

According to LINQPad's Properties dialog Server = PROSQL05, User name = sa, and Database = BIData.

So how does that knowledge affect how the SQL should be structured?

Comment: **Server name** : `PROSQL05` , **Database Name** : `sa` , **Schema Name**  : `BIData`  & **Table Name**  : `PriceExceptionHistoryCSR `. If the above information is correct then you will not get that error

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: @swe: The query shown.

Comment: @Prdp: I assume what I have selected for Connection (PROSQL05.sa.BIData) indicates that  those are such, correct?

Comment: To almost echo what Prdp said - are you sure your database names arent `cpsdata` and `bidata`? Because at the moment you're treating those two as *schema names* both with a database called `sa` - that seems unlikely.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon i think your "sa" in your Connection (Connection Name?!) is the USER (sa - Standard-SQL-Server-Non-Windows-Auth-DB-Admin). I've NEVER seen a schema called sa. The standard schema is "dbo"

Comment: According to LINQPad's Properties dialog Server = PROSQL05, User name = sa, and Database = BIData. So how does that affect what the SQL should be?

Comment: look at my updated answer please

Comment: i upvoted @Jamiec s answer, because it is detailed. but there is nothing new compared to my answer why i find it somehow unfair to accept his answer coming minutes after mine with the same solution and just some more text, while my answer helped you solving the problem...

Comment: @swe Im sorry that seems unfair - All I can say is that writing *good* answers on SO is something that is learned over time. Give as much detail as possible, and think not just about *this* user, but every person in future that might have a similar question. What background information might be helpful to *future visitors to this question*

Comment: @swe: Thanks for your answer, it did help; but Jamiec's was better and had more universal appeal. Normally, if I have to choose between two good answers, I give it to the cat with fewer points, but if one answer is markedly superior to another, I have to go with that one. No offense meant, don't take it personally. Remember: you are not your code (or your SO answers).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When addressing a database you *always* have to use this form

```
<servername>.<databasename>.<schemaname>.<tablename>
```

If your connection is on the same server, you can omit the first part, leaving you with

```
<databasename>.<schemaname>.<tablename>
```

If your connection is to the same database you can omit the first part again

```
<schemaname>.<tablename>
```

But lets back up, you're trying to access another database on the same server. Which means that one of the databases you can omit and the other you must specify. I'm going to assume all your tables are in the schema `dbo` which is *probably* the case.

You should be querying like this if your connection is directly to `bidata`

```
SELECT TOP 8 M.membername, 
             P.* 
FROM   dbo.priceexceptionhistorycsr P 
       JOIN cpsdata.dbo.members M 
         ON P.memberno = M.memberno 
WHERE  invoicedate BETWEEN '2016-09-04' AND '2016-09-10' 
ORDER  BY invoicedate
```

Answer (score 1):

googeling your errormessage shows, that this is not a linqpad message, but an sql-server-error.
So, there seems to be an error in your query.
I think, there is one of

- a typo
- an acl-problem

Are you sure your user is allowed to access both databases/schemata?

Assuming your "connection" is not what it seems to be (and obviously, according to your last comment to the question, IS not), try that:

```
SELECT TOP 8 M.membername, 
             P.* 
FROM   priceexceptionhistorycsr P 
       JOIN prosql05.cpsdata.dbo.members M 
         ON P.memberno = M.memberno 
WHERE  invoicedate BETWEEN '2016-09-04' AND '2016-09-10' 
ORDER  BY invoicedate
```

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: to the given information that is the best thing possible... but i agree

Comment: I realize it's a SQL error; what's an "acl-problem"?

Comment: @B.ClayShannon - ACL is access control list. Basically he's saying "Are you sure the user has permissions". I know for a fact you get a different error message entirely if that is the case, so I'd ignore.

Comment: @Jamiec: The user is me, and I can access either database (BIData or CPSData) as long as that is connection I select in the Connection dropdown in LINQPad; it's just trying to "mix and match" that is proving problematic.

Comment: what exacly is that in the connection dropdown? I don't think it is Server.Database.Schema. It is a simple string representing a (pre-)configured connection and seems to be something like Server.User.Database

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 8 prosql05.cpsdata.sa.M.membername, 
             P.* 
FROM   prosql05.bidata.sa.priceexceptionhistorycsr P 
       JOIN prosql05.cpsdata.sa.members M 
         ON P.memberno = M.memberno 
WHERE  invoicedate BETWEEN '2016-09-04' AND '2016-09-10' 
ORDER  BY invoicedate
```

Can you try this.Looks like your schema name is sa and you are putting your schema name before your database name in the original query

Comment: looking at the query the part after first (.) is supposed to be the database name and after second (.) is the schema name. If you look at the question  it is saying he is trying to query two databases so "sa" cannot be database name and has to be the query name

Answer (score 0):

To make your code clean, use **synonyms** for Objects of another db.

For example, if you create a synonym `sa.priceexceptionhistorycsr` for target object `prosql05.bidata.sa.priceexceptionhistorycsr`, you can refer the target with synonym only.

Comment: This does not appear to answer the questions, and although this is useful (and correct!) information it is more of a comment than an answer. When you get more rep, you will be able to comment on other users questions.